# OLS Residuals sum to zero for each submodel for a model with categorical variable?

Tags: categorical-data, least-squares, categorical-encoding

I understand that in OLS regression, the sum of the residuals for the entire model must be zero. However, does this property also guarantee that the sum of residuals within each subgroup defined by a categorical variable is zero?

If I have a categorical variable $X_2 \in \{0, 1\}$ and some continuous variable $X_1$ such that my full model is:

$Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_1 + \beta_2 X_2$

and my two sub-models are:

$Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_1$

$Y = (\beta_0 + \beta_2) + \beta_1 X_1$

Do the residuals of each sub-model always sum to zero?

Comment: $1)$ Where does $X_2$ arise in your model? $//$ $2)$ Which variable is categorical?

Comment: $X_2$ is categorical.  Full model would be $Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_1 + \beta_2 X_2$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for instance, consider the sum of residuals for $X_2 = 0$:$$\sum (Y_i - \hat{Y}_i)I\{X_{2, i} = 0 \} = \sum (Y_i - \hat{\beta}_0 - \hat{\beta}_1X_{1, i} - \hat{\beta}_2X_{2, i})(1-X_{2, i}) = \sum (Y_i - \hat{\beta}_0 - \hat{\beta}_1X_{1, i} - \hat{\beta}_2X_{2, i}) - \sum (Y_i - \hat{\beta}_0 - \hat{\beta}_1X_{1, i} - \hat{\beta}_2X_{2, i})X_{2, i} = 0$$
the last line follows from the fact that both terms are zeroes which follows from the first order conditions.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is formulated in terms of the OLS estimate of the intercept, which I believe is a well known formula for regression users. More formally/mathematically, an answer in terms of derivatives of the sum of squares set equal to zero could be developed, but I hope the answer below is convincing too.

Suppose we have the simple linear model $ Y = b_0 + b_1X_1 + e$ where $b_0$, $b_1$ and $e$ are the sample estimates of the corresponding unknown population parameters. The OLS estimate $b_0$ equals $\bar{Y}-b_1\bar{X_1}$. For the sum of the $e$ terms we then get:

$\sum{e} = \sum{Y}-\sum{b_0} - b_1\sum{X_1} = N\bar{Y} - N(\bar{Y}-b_1\bar{X_1}) -b_1N\bar{X_1}=0$

So, in our "one and only" group the error terms sum to zero. Given $b_1$, choosing $b_0$ in the way mentioned, leads to the smallest sum of squared error terms for the group.

Now look at your example. There, we have two groups, say A (if X2=0) and B (if X2=1). The models for the two groups can also be written as

$Y_A = b_0 + b_1 X_{1A} + e_A$
$Y_B = b_3 + b_1 X_{1B} + e_B$

with $b_3=b_0 + b_2$ and subscripts A an B are used for $Y$ and $X_1$ in the two groups.

The OLS estimates for the two intercepts are now:

$b_0=\bar{Y}_A-b_1\bar{X}_{1A}$
$b_3=\bar{Y}_B-b_1\bar{X}_{1B}$

As a result, in EACH of the groups, the error terms sum to zero. Given $b_1$, choosing both intercepts in the way mentioned, leads to the smallest sum of squared errors in both groups, and hence, for the total group.